# Older messages in my WhatsApp are deleting automatically

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Older messages in my WhatsApp are deleting automatically. I'm not deleting them. I thought maybe someone is using my WhatsApp account, so I deleted my account 3 times, but still the same thing is happening. Can anyone tell me what's happening with my WhatsApp, and how to fix it?

Comment: You probably have some app that make some cleanup on older things...
I have an app that delete duplicated photos and other media, and deletes messages with my authorization - I have configured it to delete messages older than 2 months.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly is the deletion happening? WhatsApp has an option wherein the sender can unsend (or delete) a message he has sent within a limited period of time. So, if you are referring to that, then it is a WhatsApp feature.

However, if even your own messages are getting deleted, then it is something else.WhatsApp does not have any option to automatically delete the older messages. So, we can rule out the fact that it is happening automatically.

Next, it is possible that someone else has access to your WhatsApp messages via WhatsApp Web. You should check the WhatsApp Web option on your phone and ensure that there are no authorized devices which you do not know. If you do not know what WhatsApp Web is, then you should not have any connected computers on your WhatsApp Web.

Comment: i have checked if someone is using my whatsApp via whatsApp web,but it was asking to scan QR code, that means no one is using my account ,so i don't know whats happening . and about how are the messages are deleting , if you send me a message today , then it will be gone by tomorrow..